# How to open and run React-Native app?

Tags: npm, react-native

I'm new to React and React-Native I'm trying to open a React-native app I cloned from github. I've done a npm install and I did a npm start in the command line. It says: "Running Packager on port 8081" and then a bunch of other builds beneath it. I tried going to local host 8081 and 8081/hot but I can't see the app. Does anyone know how to run and test an react-native app on the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow the below step

```
1) Go to project directory
```

after use this CLI

```
2) react-native run-android
```

it can run only either emulator or real device so we can first start the emulator after the try above command

[more details see this doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Inside your project directory for bundle js.

```
3) react-native start
```

or

```
3) react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: this is a good answer! Should've look more deeply into the docs. thanks anyway bud!

Answer (score 0):

After installing packages,
 open src folder--->open in terminal
--->`$ npm start`

Answer (score 0):

react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 5s"

Answer (score 0):

If you have an installation with `android` and `ios` folders, you should run `yarn android` or `yarn ios`.